# Where is DUnit under Delphi XE?

Tags: delphi, dunit

Looks like DUNIT is already integrated under Delphi XE. But I can't find it.
My questions are:

1. How can I access it? Do I have to install it manually? I don't remember Delphi setup to ask me if I want to install DUnit.
2. If I have to install it manually, is it better to download the latest version from sourceforge.net or maybe the version delivered by Embarcadero (on Delphi's CD) (if it exists) integrates better with Delphi?

Update:
I purchased Delphi without CD (the downloadable version). Maybe it is smaller than the version delivered on CD so some tools like DUnit are not included?

Comment: no entry at C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\8.0\source\dUnit\src ?

Comment: Hi Bummi. The path exists. The code is there. So it looks DUnit was installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dUnit is usually installed with Delphi XE, and you can start a new test project from within the IDE.

For example, launch IDE Insight by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> and then start writing `test project`, you'll get:

[image]

Press enter and you'll be presented an expert to configure your test project using DUnit.

Answer (score 2):

You can always get dunit from sourceforge:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/dunit/

The latest changes are some merges from the embarcadero repository. 
However, most major updates seem to be from an era before stuff like generics, anonymous functions and operator overloaders existed.

Answer (score 2):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/dunit3/
Here is DUnit for Embarcadero RAD Studio XE

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Found it. I can create a DUnit file from:

File -> New -> Other... -> Delphi projects -> Delphi files -> Dunit.